# Is there a System Restore in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 12.04, restore

I'm thinking about installing the desktop on my Ubuntu Server (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`).

Is there a "system restore" I can run in case I don't want the desktop anymore?

Comment: That's what we call a `backup` ;-)

Comment: I see you can use `Déjà Dup` (http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/) but what option is there for the server? This looks like it is used on the desktop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can just `apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop` and `apt-get autoremove` to clean up the dependencies.

Comment: You may want to expand this to explain how this will only work if *nothing* has been manually installed (or marked as manually installed) that depends on `ubuntu-desktop`, since `ubuntu-desktop` was installed. Furthermore, anything that's been installed manually that depends on something that was installed automatically as a dependency of `ubuntu-desktop` may prevent large amounts of software from being autoremoved. There's a reason techniques [like this](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu) have been developed. (Please note *that* won't solve *this* problem; it's for a similar problem.)

Comment: @EliahKagan, huh?  It will work just fine; it will just remove whatever you installed that depends on the desktop.